# PWA Cors request in SPA

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-httpclient, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a simple web application with angular 5 that will take banking exchange rates and make calculation for the user in the currency that he requires.  The banking site does not have cors enabled. Is there a way in PWA to side step the cors issue without making a proxy ?

For the get request I use http client from '@angular/common/http' library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a quote from [Google PWA docs](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api) on Cross-domain/cross-origin request.

> Custom headers on cross-origin requests must be supported by the
>   server from which the resource is requested.

If your bank blocks the cross-origin requests, you can't do anything about it. They want to secure their resources only for their domain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i wasn't sure if it can be done, thanks for the confirmation